# Get values from the ListView and display on a label in JavaFX

Tags: java, list, javafx, javafx-8

There's a list in a listView and there is a label to display the items that I selected. But when selecting more than one the label only shows one (the newest selection). What I want is to display all the items that I select.

Please help me with this I've been stuck here for a long time

This is the FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="373.0" prefWidth="648.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.trial.HelloController">
  <children>
    <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="289.0" />
    <Label fx:id="selection" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="Your selection">
      <font>
        <Font size="17.0" />
      </font>
    </Label>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This the controller

```
package com.example.trial;


import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView;

    @FXML
    private Label selection;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        String[] items = {"Java","C#","C","C++","Python"};
        listView.getItems().addAll(items);
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<? super String>) c -> selectionChanged());
    }

    private void selectionChanged(){
        ObservableList<String> selectedItems = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        String getSelectedItem = (selectedItems.isEmpty())?"No Selected Item":selectedItems.toString();
        selection.setText(getSelectedItem);
    }
}
```

This is main

```
package com.example.trial;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

label shows only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Info**

Your code works, I tried it local.

**Solution**

On the picture, you have only one item selected. Please select many items with CTRL + left click, if you want to select many items. :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: ah yes, thank u, but how to do it with one click without using CRTL

Comment: This is not supported out of the box (I think). You need to create an alogrithm for it, which has a List of selectedItems which is preloaded with the selected items until now. Then you need to add the new selected item to the list, and dann you need to set all items in the selectedItemsList to selected. My tip: Place a Label above or under the list which tells you to "Please use CTRL ..." .

Comment: OK, Thank u very much ❤️